SharePoint Global Navigation Blank
I am struggling with getting the Global navigation working, not sure if I am doing something wrong or if its a timing issue?
I have read many MS and other pages and videos on Navigation and hub sites and think I understand it a bit but clearly I am missing something.
Steps Taken
Via SharePoint Admin & Site Settings & PowerShell

Created a Comm site (HomeSite)
Set as the Home site, via PS [Set-SPOHomeSite -HomeSiteUrl https://...]
Registered the HomeSite to a Hub site
Changed the "look and feel" on the HomeSite, eg theme colors, layout
The Global Navigation link is shown under the site's Settings menu with;
Enable global nav "On"
Changed custom logo for visual testing (and is shown on all pages now)
Confirmed Hub Settings is "Shown in navigation"
Associated another site (Site2), with the HomeSite
Created two more Comms sites (HrDeptHub) & (Onboarding)
Associated Onboarding to the HrDeptHub site
Added a parent association to the HrDeptHub to the HomeSite

But in the end, I am not seeing any menu changes (horizontal page menus on the Comms site) and the Global Navigation is empty. I am logged into the site as the Site Owner and have a test user with basic permissions only.

Oddly the Theme settings/colors on the HomeSite (hub) are not propagating to the associated sites. In another test with 2 brand new sites (CommSite1 hub) & (Teamsite1), branding/colors are enforced on the associated TeamSite1. But I the Global Nav is empty and the top Hub navigation (horizontal) only shows items from the site itself.
EDIT: After a day or so the Themes/colors from the hub site have propagated but the Global Navigation is still empty.
